# oracle sql query to display same salary

Tags: sql, database, oracle

employee table

empid(integer)
emp_name(varchar)
salary(integer)
location(varchar)

display employees who have same salary.

how to solve this?

Comment: show us your efforts.. what you have tried??

Comment: SELECT empid,emp_name,salary,location FROM employee WHERE salary=(??) subquery in place of ??... I cannot understand how to write the subquery...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the results:

Since you need same salary hence i have grouped out the result with respect to salary and then used a listagg function to retrieve all the employee names with a delimiter.

```
select salary,listagg(emp_name,' | ') within group (order by emp_name) "Employees"
from employee 
group by salary;
```

Answer (score -1):

`Select * from employee where salary is not null`

Comment: This question is very poorly phrased and, in its current state, does not really merit answering. However, your answer still does not meet the desired end state the OP asked for. It is blatantly incorrect.